# Hot to Neutral at the outlet only reading 112V

Tags: electrical, multimeter

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue.  All outlets downstream from my GFCI will not work when I plug anything in.  with my DMM I pulled the GFCI from the wall and measured voltage into the GFCI from Hot to Ground = 120 Neutral to ground = .5 Neutral to hot 120.  Out from the GFCI Hot to Ground = 120 Neutral to ground = .5 Neutral to hot 120.  I go to the next outlet and I get Hot to ground 120. Neutral to ground 1.5 Hot to Neutral 112v.  any ideas on how to resolve?  When I trip the GFCI all reading on the outlet goes to almost 0 as would be expected.  It is important to note I have replace the outlet not working to no avail. I get the same readings without an outlet attached

Answer (score 2):

Loose neutral on either the GFCI, the socket under test, or an intermediate socket.

Comment: Yep, classic loose or high resistance neutral connection somewhere.